# I want to verify my login details with custom saved data in vf page

Tags: apex

Here is my controller

```
public class candidateRegistrationClass {
    ApexPages.StandardController controller;

    //public Credentials__c c{get;set;}

    public string noResults{ get; set; }

    public List<Credentials__c> clist{get;set;}

    public candidateRegistrationClass(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
    {
        this.controller=controller;
    }

    public PageReference loggedin()
    {
        clist =new List<Credentials__c>([select Id,CandidateID__c,Name from Credentials__c]);
        for(Credentials__c c:clist){
            if(clist[0].Name==c.Name && clist[0].CandidateID__c==c.CandidateID__c)
            {
                PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('https://c.ap2.visual.force.com/apex/position_detail_wraper');
                return pageRef;
            }
            else {
                noResults='Enter valid Credentials';
                return null;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Page Code

```
<apex:page standardController="Credentials__c" extensions="candidateRegistrationClass">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" title="Candidate Login">
                <apex:inputField value="{!Credentials__c.CandidateID__c}"/>
                <apex:inputSecret value="{!Credentials__c.Name}"/>
                <apex:commandButton action="{!loggedin}" value="Login" />
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:outputText value="{!noResults}" style="font-weight:800"/>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: So what issue you are facing here.

Comment: if I am not entereing the correct details it is navigating to other page

Comment: <apex:page standardController="Credentials__c" extensions="candidateRegistrationClass">
<apex:form >
 <apex:pageBlock >
 <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" title="Candidate Login">
 <apex:inputField value="{!Credentials__c.CandidateID__c}"/> 
   <apex:inputSecret value="{!Credentials__c.Name}"/>
 <apex:commandButton action="{!loggedin}" value="Login" />
  </apex:pageBlockSection>
   <apex:outputText value="{!noResults}" style="font-weight:800"/>
 </apex:pageBlock>
 </apex:form>
--this is my vf page

Comment: You are accessing this page from site. Which page you are redirecting. Check access of this object too.

Comment: I have created dis page to check for log in.Here I want to check details of candidate and I want to navigate to another page

Comment: Are you are accessing this page from site? Which page you are redirecting?

Comment: this page is redirected to a candidate detail page ...yes i am accessing this page from site

Comment: @John The use of a hard coded domain name should always be discouraged. There is no guarantee that this org will always be on the AP2 instance in the future. In fact, it is likely that this code will break in the future.

Comment: Yes Peter it might be .But i just want to check how to create a login page using custom objects in vf pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be modified as below:

```
public PageReference loggedin(){

  List<Credentials__c> cList = new List<Credentials__c>([select Id, CandidateID__c, Name 
                                                         from Credentials__c 
                                                         where name =: c.name AND CandidateID__c =: c.CandidateID__c]);

  if (clist != null && cList.size()>0) {
    PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('https://c.ap2.visual.force.com/apex/position_detail_wraper');
    return pageRef;
  }

  else {
    noResults='Enter valid Credentials';
  }

  return null;
}
```

Comment: Thank you....but here else statement became default and what ever input i give it is displaying else statement

Comment: Hi John.. Try to use c.name and c.CandidateId__c in the VF page instead of Credentials__c.name and Credentials__c.CandidateId__c respectively!!!

Comment: Thank you  userRg...but sorry ..now also no change if statement is not getting executed.

Comment: @userRg the use of a hard coded domain name should always be discouraged. There is no guarantee that this org will always be on the AP2 instance in the future. In fact, it is likely that this code will break in the future.

Comment: i agree @Peter.. I may be overlooked since I was looking into the logic issue. But yeah thanks for correcting me :). We always use ...PageReference('/apex/pageName'). It automatically set the domain from where it is executed.

Comment: @John, it seems you have commented the declaration statement of c variable. I'm not sure how you are doing but its usually resolve the issue when we use a getter setter variable and initialize the variable inside the constructor to use on the page.

Comment: @ userRg  for your understanding I have a custom object Credentials__c and I have 3 fields in it where one field is a lookup linked with another custom object Candidates__c   now I want a Vf page like log in page where I want to enter the password and use value from lookup field dat should be compared in the apex class and it should redirect to another page if the given details are true...Please let me know if you are not clear with this process want i want to do

Comment: Try putting system.debug statement after your query and see what you're getting from the system. This way it is easier to understand what you're getting from system.